# Strapi different models of the object with relationships

Tags: json, strapi

I have a problem with model in relationship

I have Cities and Buildings in Cities

Relationship settings:

- City belongs to many Buildings
- City has many Buildings

In cities API i see

```
{
    id: 1,
    city_name: "Chicago",       

    building: {
        id: 3,
        building_name: "SomeBuilding in City",          
        city: 1
        }
}
```

In Building API i see

```
{
    id: 3,
    building_name: "SomeBuilding in City",      

    citys: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Chicago",                
            building: 3
        }
        ]
}
```

Why in cities api in the building model city is only ID of city
But in Buildings api city is model of city?

And how to make api of cities looks like example, witch full information about city in building model

example cities API

```
{
    id: 1,
    city_name: "Chicago",       

    building: {
        id: 3,
        building_name: "SomeBuilding in City",          
        
        citys: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Chicago",                    
                building: 3
            ]
            }
    }
}
```